# How to get facebook video's original size(width & height) and how to get fql.video src_hq?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I tried to use facebook fql.video get video from my Idol's wall, then, **how to get the video's original size(width & height)**?

And I noticed one field named `src_hq` in `fql` table, in its description: *The URL to the source file for the high quality version of the video.*

but when I tried it in the browser directly. it warning:

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document you requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials
>   (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply
>   the credentials required.

So **my another question is how to play video with the `src_hq`**?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/) page is the best resource. Click on "[Try this query](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20vid,%20owner,%20title,%20description,%20thumbnail_link,%20embed_html,%20updated_time,%20created_time%20FROM%20video%20WHERE%20owner=20531316728&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAOAbMaVDwx84Vr0Nry6m8fSqDo3qWY0hI2eaKFm6ZCvY8AceUUzqt6DFwqeu9ZCaSQlo1PM7uZA3RsEdKpaVQOZCfm6naAZDZD)" which outputs a sample fql query (note: doesn't use fbapp.Fql(query). Take note of the `&access_token=.....` appended to the query. The XML output contains: `<object width="400" height="224" >` that you can use.

`src_hq` is an access problem, not a playback issue. Can the normal video be viewed on your Facebook? Usually if a high quality video is available, there is a box for [HQ], see sample [video](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=1675169722566).

Comment: hi @Alvin K. thanks for your reply, but I this `<object width="400" height="224" >` is not the `video's original size`, because all the video have this size, I think this size just like photo's `thumbnail`. a standard size generated by the bot.

Comment: @Giberno: All video feed has info encoded in it (eg: video frame size, encoding bit-rate, etc). However if the video is played via Flash player (usually), we lose this info. If you can access the feed directly, try using [media info](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MediaInfo) to analyse it.

Comment: Ok, no more better answer. close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use field `format` from FQL table `video` to get video width/height:

```
An array of various video formats available with their embed_html code and resolution
```